# Should I go directly to my manager's office if I have a question to ask him?

Tags: communication

I am a fresh graduate student who just entered the workplace. I am not a native English speaker.

What should I say if I would like to go to my manager's office to ask him a question? Sometimes I saw him busy working with some stuff and I am not sure whether I should interrupt him in the middle of something. What should I say? In the past, I used the following phases: "Excuse me. May I ask you a question please?" "Excuse me. Do you have a couple of minutes?"

Comment: "Excuse me. Do you have a couple of minutes?" - sounds good to me.

Answer (score 6):

Even if people on this site tell you the way they do it or the way it's usually done, such things can easily be completely different based on company culture.

Therefore, in my opinion, the best solution is to just ask one of your coworkers about the way it's done in your company. They will probably be glad to help you.

By-the-way: the more formal your company is (especially larger ones), the more likely it is that the answer to your main question is No.

Comment: Even better than a co-worker is asking the manager themselves.  In the next conversation saying "Hey boss, when I have a quick question should I just stop by or should I book time with you?" would cut through a lot of hassle.

Comment: I can't upvote @Myles' comment more than once or I would.  That's perfect and has ZERO risk of running afoul of some unwritten rule or cultural norm.

Answer (score 1):

If your manager is in your direct chain of command/hierarchy, and is right above you (i.e. there isn't an Assistant Manager/Lead in between you two) then by all you means you should be able to talk to him. If your organization uses Outlook, or some other event/meeting tracker, consult that so you do not drop in during a meeting/call/lunch break.

ETA: Company culture/policies may dictate against this. More rigid professional settings may require more formality than dropping in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already on speaking terms with your manager (I assume you've been introduced), then there shouldn't be any reason why you can't talk and ask questions.  You'll soon learn from body language whether it's appropriate time or not.

If your manager is more than a minutes walk away, then email is fine to use for a few basic questions - you can link this into a physical talk if required.

You shouldn't be shy about it, you'll soon learn what the appropriate level of communication is.